# SQL Select statement not returning desired columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table (sample) with 10 rows, that has columns of place_name, 5 days worth of data (day1, day2,...,day5) for each location, and a sum column (TotalSum) of the 5 days. TotalSum at the beginning is full of null values.

```
place_name | day1 | day2 | day3 | day4 | day5 | TotalSum
PlaceA     |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |     NULL
```

I have an update statement that will sum up the five days, and put them into the TotalSum column for each of the 10 locations.

```
update sample set sample.TotalSum = day1+day2+day3+day4+day5;
```

I want to then select the location (place_name) with the maximum TotalSum value. I have been trying it with the following line:

```
SELECT place_name, MAX(TotalSum) AS MAXsum FROM sample;
```

The code does not work and gives an error saying,

> "Column 'sample.place_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

If I execute the code below, then all I get is the MAXsum value, nothing else.

```
SELECT MAX(TotalSum) AS MAXsum FROM sample;
```

Working in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, 2014.

Comment: You could google it and you'd find an answer in a flash

Comment: This does not show any research effort.

Comment: Thanks @WyattShipman for the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason you are getting this message is you are trying to aggregate the column `TotalSum` but you also have a non agregated column `place_name`. but you are not defining the group which the column can be aggregated by in a `GROUP BY` clause

try this:

```
SELECT place_name, MAX(TotalSum) AS MAXsum 
FROM sample 
GROUP BY place_name
```

if you want the query to return the place_name with the maximum MAX(TotalSum) then you need to do this:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 place_name, MAX(TotalSum) AS MAXsum 
    FROM sample 
    GROUP BY place_name
    ORDER BY MAXsum DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This returns the place_name with the associated TotalSum, but it returns all the place_name(s) and orders them alphabetically instead of returning only the MAXsum and it's place_name.

Comment: @user3230654 you can restrict the data set returned to just return the place_name with the maximum MAX(TotalSum). I've edited my answer to show you how you can do this.

Comment: That's perfect. I added DESC to the end of the ORDER BY statement